# In css, can I access the value of a property from an element's parent?

Tags: css

Right now I have CSS (SASS) code that does this:

```
.container
  background-color: red
  .inner
    ...
    border-bottom-color: red
```

(in this case, the .inner is a triangle, so its border color is serving as its background color)

I'd like to avoid specifying the second 'red', something like:

```
.container
  background-color: red
  .inner
    border-bottom-color: attr(parent.background-color)
```

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS? (I can do it using SASS variables, or JS, or whatnot, but I'd like to stay within CSS.)

Comment: I don't think that is possible..

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Phil... It's not quite the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) are in a very [early stage of the specification process](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/).

This is something that will definitely come, but you can't really use it nowadays. (MDN states that Fx 29 supports it already)

Example:

```
::root {
    var-brand-color: red;
}

.container {
    background-color: var( brand-color );
}
.container .inner {
    border-bottom-color: var( brand-color );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way (currently) to do this in pure CSS, but since you mentioned you're using SASS, you could simply use a variable:

```
$myColor: red

.container
    background-color: $myColor
    .inner
        border-bottom-color: $myColor
```

**Edit**

Depending on how the rest of your CSS is structured and since you're dealing with `border-color` you can set either `border-color` or `color` on `.container` and then set `border-bottom-color: inherit;` on `.inner`:

```
.container {
    border-color: red;
    background-color: red;
}

.container .inner { border-bottom-color: inherit; }
```

This is specific to the properties in your example, however. There is no way to explicitly inherit values across different properties.

Comment: As mentioned in the body of the question, I am more interested in the existence (or not) of a CSS solution...

Comment: @AlexFeinman There is no CSS solution. `inherit` is the closest thing that's similar to what you're trying to do, but is only intended to inherit the values of the *same* properties.